# regular expression, not reading entire string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a standard expression that is not working correctly. 
This expression is supposed to catch if a string has invalid characters anywhere in the string. It works perfect on RegExr.com but not in my tests.

The exp is: `/[a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]/g`

It is failing on : `@#@#` 
but passing with : `aa@#@#`

It should fail both times, what am I doing wrong?

Also, `/^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]$/g`         matches nothing...

```
//All Boxs
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {

            var text = $(this).prop("value")
            var textTest = /[a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]/g.test(text)

            if (!textTest && text != "") {
                allFieldsValid = false
                $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(224, 0, 0, 0.29)")
                alert("Invalid characters found in " + text + " \n\n Valid characters are:\n A-Z a-z 0-9 ' . -")
            }
            else {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF")
                $(this).prop("value", text)
            }
        });
```

edit:added code

Comment: If this is truly [tag:C#], then why are you using pattern delimiters?

Comment: @KennethK. sorry i guess c# has nothing to do with it, I added the code

Comment: What all things do you wan't to allow ? or exclude ?

Comment: Well, changing question tag to C# and showing your code makes it all clear.

Comment: @NEO-xx , only Allow those chars, (a-z)(A-Z)( ' .  -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION RE-TAGGING**

You need to use

```
var textTest = /^[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]+$/.test(text)
                                  ^^
```

Note the absence of `/g` modifier and the `+` quantifier. There are [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results) when you use `/g` global modifier within a regex used in `RegExp#test()` function.

You may shorten it a bit with the help of the `/i` case insensitive modifier:

```
var textTest = /^[A-Z0-9'.-]+$/i.test(text)
```

Also, as I mention below, you do not have to escape the `-` at the end of the character class `[...]`, but it is advisable to keep escaped if the pattern will be modified later by less regex-savvy developers.

**ORIGINAL C#-RELATED DETAILS**

Ok, say, you are using `Regex.IsMatch(str, @"[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]")`. The `Regex.IsMatch` searches for *partial matches* inside a string. So, if the input string contains an ASCII letter, digit, `'`, `.` or `-`, this will pass. Thus, it is logical that `aa@#@#` passes this test, and `@#@#` does not.

If you use the second one as `Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]$")`, only 1 character strings (with an optional newline at the end) would get matched as `^` matches at the start of the string, `[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]` matches 1 character from the specified ranges/sets, and `$` matches the end of the string (or right before the final newline).

So, you need a quantifier (`+` to match 1 or more, or `*` to match zero or more occurrences) and the anchors `\A` and `\z`:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\A[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]+\z")
                     ^^              ^^^
```

`\A` matches the start of string (always) and `\z` matches the very end of the string in .NET. The `[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]+` will match 1+ characters that are either ASCII letters, digits, `'`, `.` or `-`.

Note that `-` at the end of the character class does not have to be escaped (but you may keep the `\-` if some other developers will have to modify the pattern later).

And please be careful where you test your regexps. Regexr only supports JavaScript regex syntax. To test .NET regexps, use [RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) or [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester).

Comment: Thanks! ,     /^[a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]+$/  failed at RegExr.com but seems to work perfect in the page

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]+$/g
```

In the second case your (`/[a-zA-Z0-9'.-]/g`) was working because it matched on the first letter, so to make it correct you need to match the whole string (use `^` and `$`) and also allow more letters by adding a `+` or `*` (if you allow empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex it matches any char which isn't part of the allowed charset

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]+/g
```

Test

```
>>regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]+/g
/[^a-zA-Z0-9'.\-]+/g
>>regex.test( "@###dsfdfjsakldfj")
true
>>regex.test( "dsfdfjsakldfj")
false
```